# Can we deduce that set of $a,b,c$ is the whole set of integers?

Tags: prime-numbers

We say that three positive integers $x,y,z$ are coprime if there exist three integers $a,b,c$ such that $$ax+by+cz=1$$

if we run $x,y,z$ over all possible coprime positive integers. Can we deduce that set of $a,b,c$ is the **whole** set of integers?

Comment: Using your own definition, $|a|,|b|,|c|$ must (also) be coprime, since if (for example) $a < 0$, then there must be a corresponding solution with $|a| > 0$ and $x \to (-x).$

Comment: @user2661923: Can you convert this into a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Per OP's request, I am amplifying my comment into an answer.  **However**, I am **not** saying that the (constraint-1) shown below is the **only** constraint that $|a|, |b|, |c|$ may have to satisfy.  I am merely saying that (constraint-1) has to be satisfied.

> We say that three positive integers $x,y,z$ are coprime if there exist three integers $a,b,c$ such that $$ax+by+cz=1$$

It is easy to establish that under the above definition, if for any given $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z},$ there happens to exist positive integers $x,y,z$ with

$$ax+by+cz=1$$

then there must exist integers $x_1, y_1, z_1$ such that

$$(x_1 \times |a|) + (y_1 \times |b|) + (z_1 \times |c|) = 1. \tag{constraint-1}$$

Simply set 
$x_1 = [x : ~\text{if}~ a > 0, ~\text{else}~ (-x)]$ 
$y_1 = [y : ~\text{if}~ b > 0, ~\text{else}~ (-y)]$ 
$z_1 = [z : ~\text{if}~ c > 0, ~\text{else}~ (-z)]$.

The only **flaw** in concluding that $|a|, |b|, |c|$ must therefore be coprime, is that one or two of $a,b,c$ could be equal to **zero**.  However, if you are given that each of $a,b,c$ is non-zero, then $|a|, |b|, |c|$ must be coprime, using the OP's definition.